# OCMock test fails to build: Foundation/Foundation.h : No such file or directory

Tags: xcode, ocmock

I am a Xcode beginner, and am facing some problems in compiling an OCMock test. I have added the OCMock.framework in "Groups & Files", and then added a very basic OCMock test from the Unit testing target, basically for Canary testing.

When I compile the OCMockTests.m file, the system returns around 38 errors pointing out all the imported headers that is in OCMock.Framework files to be non-existent, and in the top comes "Foundation/Foundation.h : No such file or directory". But when I compile the OCMock.Framework, then everything succeeds. I tried replacing Foundation.h with NSObject.h, but the system is not even able to find that.

I reckon it is some linker error....the system is somehow probably not able to get the location of Sentest.Framework. BTW, I have updated the Executable info - environment variable - DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH with the correct (?) Sentest framework path (the argument is "-Sentest All"), that is of the IphoneOS folder.

Need your advices...thanks a bunch.
~ Sayan

Answer (score 1):

See [Colin Barrett's "OCMock and the iPhone" tutorial](http://iamthewalr.us/blog/2008/11/ocmock-and-the-iphone/).